# Using display: table-cell how can align multiple buttons inside a <div> to the right

Tags: html, css

I created the following fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YN2rz/

Which is:

```
<div style="display: table; width: 100%">
  <div style="display: table-row;">
    <div style="display: table-cell;">

    <div style="display: table-row;">
        <div style="display: table-cell;">
            <button>Left 1</button>
        </div>
        <div style="display: table-cell;">
            <button>Left 2</button>
        </div>
        <div style="display: table-cell;">
            <button>Left 3</button>
        </div>
        <div style="display: table-cell;">
            Some text
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div style="display: table-cell;text-align:right">
        <button>Right 1</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This gives three buttons on the left, some text and one button on the right.

However I need to have a new layout with one button on the left and three on the right and minimum space between the buttons. Can anyone help suggest how I can do this?

Comment: [DID you mean this](http://jsfiddle.net/YN2rz/3/) ?

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/YN2rz/4/) will do it (`one button left, some text and three buttons right`)

```
<div style="display: table; width: 100%">
    <div style="display: table-cell;">
        <button>Left 1</button>
    </div>
    <div style="display: table-cell;">Some text</div>
    <div style="display: table-cell;text-align:right">
        <button>Right 1</button>
        <button>Right 2</button>
        <button>Right 3</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

But, there are other ways, without using inline style. Also, you can use [this](http://jsfiddle.net/YN2rz/5/)

**HTML:**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="btn_left">
        <button>Left 1</button>
    </div>
    <div id="text">Some text</div>
    <div id="btn_right">
        <button>Right 1</button>
        <button>Right 2</button>
        <button>Right 3</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#btn_left, #btn_right, #text{
    display:inline-block;
}
#btn_right{
    float:right;
}
```

**Update :** Using a table, you may try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/YN2rz/6/).

Comment: I notice here you don't have table-row. Was that on purpose ?

Comment: @Melina, Well, I can use `table` but you didn't use a table and I thought you want it without a `table`.

Comment: What I meant was you have display: table and display: table-cell but you don't have a display: table-row.